# Word meaning "of many different kinds" in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a meal that consists *of many different kinds* of food (in a way that gives pleasure) similiar to the word *varied* I guess, but used in this context:

let's say Johnny and his little sister arrived at the dinner table for dinner their mom prepared. They're blown away by what's in front of them; there's fish, chicken, pork, soup, and even Johnny's favourite spaghetti and meatballs and more. Dinner is usually pretty plain with only a few simple dishes that's it, but I guess mom's in a good mood today so she decided to treat them with a special dinner. And Johnny may say "wow mom, today's dinner is pretty [that word]!"

What is the word I'm looking for?

Comment: polyphagous .. I came across your question while looking for another word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Feast* comes to mind.

If it is served as a buffet, *smorgasbord* which is an excellent Scandinavian loan word!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear, but I kind of looking for a word that describes the meal, rather than the meal itself.

Comment: That statement was less clear than the question before it. I believe you are asking for a descriptor rather than the type of meal?

Comment: In which case, I'd say *Quite a feast!* Or I would say this is a veritable *smorgasbord*!

Comment: *Spread* works too.

Comment: @Nilloc Absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an adjective, you might try *eclectic*. [Definition from Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic), particularly definition 2.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, Mom, today's dinner's really SUMPTUOUS! (sumptuous banquets, sumptuous feasts)

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sumptuous) defines this adjective as:

> Of a size or splendor suggesting great expense; lavish

[Here are some photos showing a sumptuous dinner](https://www.google.cz/search?q=sumptuous+dinner&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=kmIGU-ynHbOI7Aa89IDoDA&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=661).

Answer (score 0):

Not a word little Johnny would be likely to use, but in principle...

> [***heterogeneous***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heterogeneous) *- composed of parts of different kinds; having widely dissimilar elements or constituents*

In practice, he's probably just say *pretty **varied***, or perhaps *a real **assortment***.

Answer (score 0):

If I were Johnny, I'd say, "Wow Mom!  Today's dinner is quite a **hodgepodge**!"

Hodgepodge [definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&safe=strict#q=hodgepodge%20meaning&safe=strict) and other good synonyms:

> 1. a confused mixture.
>
> "Rob's living room was a hodgepodge of modern furniture and antiques"
>
> **synonyms**: mixture, mix, mixed bag, assortment, random collection, conglomeration, jumble, ragbag, grab bag, miscellany, medley, salmagundi, potpourri, patchwork, pastiche

Comment: If the dinner was comprised of a mishmash of sundry leftovers, I think _hodgepodge_ would be perfect. If everything was prepared from scratch, however, and the dishes were designed to complement each other, then I think I'd probably prefer _smorgasbord_ and avoid _hodgepodge_ – out of fear of insulting the cook!

Comment: @J.R., I know I'm splitting hairs but it's still slightly ambiguous whether or not Johnny's mom prepared all those dishes fresh, from scratch, or if her good mood resulted from her being able to empty the fridge of all last weeks leftovers.  lol!

Comment: I wouldn't call it "splitting hairs" so much as "two valid suggestions useful in two different contexts".

Answer (score 0):

How about "`lavish`"?

> "Mom prepared a *lavish* meal for the whole family."

From [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lavish):

> **lavish**  —adj
>     1.      prolific, abundant, or profuse
>     2.      generous; unstinting; liberal
>     3.      extravagant; prodigal; wasteful: lavish expenditure
>     —vb
>     4.      (tr) to give, expend, or apply abundantly, generously, or in profusion

Answer (score 0):

How about extravagant? "Wow, Mom, today's dinner is pretty extravagant."